# C++ Builder / Winapi Different loading/progressbar type

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

How do I create a "loading" ProgressBar like the one shown below? I don't even know how to Google for it. I'm looking for a kind of floating green bar that moves back and forth:

[image]

Not a standard ProgressBar like this:

[image]

Comment: Start by reading the progress bar docs

Comment: Voted to re-open the question. Not a single one of the close-voters understands the platform well enough to make an educated judgement. The reason for closing this question does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you have to set a standard [Progress Bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760818.aspx)'s control style to [PBS_MARQUEE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760820.aspx). This can be done either through the dialog's resource script, or changed at runtime by calling [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx).

To start and stop the marquee animation and control its speed, send a [PBM_SETMARQUEE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760842.aspx) message to the control.

Using this style requires version 6.0 of the common controls.

> To use Comctl32.dll version 6, specify it in a manifest. For more information on manifests, see [**Enabling Visual Styles**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx).

Sample code:

```
LONG_PTR style = ::GetWindowLongPtrW( hWndPB, GWL_STYLE );
style &= ~( PBS_SMOOTH | PBS_SMOOTHREVERSE | PBS_VERTICAL);  // Remove competing styles
style |= PBS_MARQUEE;                                        // Add the marquee style
::SetWindowLongPtrW( hWndPB, GWL_STYLE, style );
::SendMessageW( hWndPB, PBM_SETMARQUEE, TRUE, 0 );
```

Note: You cannot use the marquee style with vertical progress bar controls.